# AWS appsync w/ Lambd function backend, GraphQL gives unexpected repsonce to Query

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

What follows is all in the AWS console.  My lambda function defines `deletePost`

```
case "deletePost":
   var id = event.arguments.id;
   callback(null, {id:-1,author:"me",title:"title"}); //note, regardless of what your args are right now it is returning id:-1
   break;
```

My schema is

```
type Mutation {
   ...
   deletePost(id: ID!): Post!
}
type Post {
   id: ID!
   author: String!
   title: String
}
```

and my graphiQL query is

```
mutation DeletePost{
 deletePost(id: 3){
  id
 }  
}
```

For some reason it just parrots `id=3` back to me when i've hard coded id as -1?  If I ask for author or title to be return in my query I don't get them back at all.

---

Update  full lambs fxn.  Just a slightly modified version of the template that is provided with the aws appSync docs.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
console.log("Received event {}", JSON.stringify(event, 3));
var posts = { //in memory array store (simulates DB)
    "1": {"id": "1", "title": "First book", "author": "Author1"},
    "2": {"id": "2", "title": "Second book", "author": "Author2"},
    "3": {"id": "3", "title": "Third book", "author": "Author3"},
    "4": {"id": "4", "title": "Fourth book", "author": "Author4"},
    "5": {"id": "5", "title": "Fifth book", "author": "Author5"} };

console.log("Got an Invoke Request: "+event.field);
switch(event.field) {
    case "getPost":
        var id = event.arguments.id;
        callback(null, posts[id]);
        break;
    case "updatePost":
        posts[event.arguments.id]=event.arguments;
        console.log(posts);
        callback(null, event.arguments);
        break;
    case "deletePost":
        var id = event.arguments.id;
        //delete posts[event.arguments.id];
        callback(null, {id:-1,author:"me",title:"tits"});
        break;
    case "allPosts":
        var values = [];
        for(var d in posts){
            values.push(posts[d]);
        }
        callback(null, values);
        break;
    case "addPost":
        var id = event.arguments.id;
        posts[id]=event.arguments;
        console.log(posts);
        callback(null, event.arguments);
        break;
    case "addPostErrorWithData":
        var id = event.arguments.id;
        var result = posts[id];
        // attached additional error information to the post
        result.errorMessage = 'Error with the mutation, data has changed';
        result.errorType = 'MUTATION_ERROR';
        callback(null, result);
        break;
    default:
        callback("Unknown field, unable to resolve" + event.field, null);
        break;
  }
};
```

Resolvers.  For the most part just pass the data straight through.

```
#request mapping
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Invoke",
    "payload": {
        "field": "addPost",
        "arguments":  $util.toJson($context.arguments)
    }
}
#responce mapping
$util.toJson($context.result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know without seeing all of the Lambda function and also your resolver templates. From the above code I'm going to guess you used this tutorial as a starting point: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html

Assuming you're passing back the result in the response template, like `$util.toJson($context.result)`, then the issue is most likely with the structure of the callback in your Lambda function

```
let result = {"id" :-1, "author":"me", "title":"title"}
callback(null, result);
```

Essentially you need to pass back a result object for it to be seen in the `$context` object and converted as a GraphQL JSON response to the caller.

Comment: Damn it.  I had "addPost" in the deletePost resolver.  It really sucks having all these functions hidden away in various random places in the AWS web console.  Wish they could all just be in files in project in VSCode.  Why does the callback take null as first arguement.  Is that put onto $context as a different field?

Comment: That's part of the handler lifecycle for a NodeJS function in Lambda, which is necessary so that it has an entry and exit point for your function invocation. You can read more about that here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html